# Поведение функции date с форматами w и N

Tags: дата, php, format

Случайно обнаружил странность. Это конечно же не проблема для меня, но просто хочу разобраться, где я провтыкал.
Итак, вычислим порядковый номер дня недели.

```
// v1 - с использованием формата w
echo date('w', strtotime('2014-03-21')); // 5
// не имеет значения, но и так
echo date('w', mktime(0,0,0,3,21,2014)); // 5
// v2 - теперь возьмем формат N (стандарт ISO-8601)
echo date('N', strtotime('2014-03-21')); // 5
// ну и так же
echo date('N', mktime(0,0,0,3,21,2014)); // 5
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> N Порядковый номер дня недели в соответствии со стандартом ISO-8601 (добавлен в версии PHP 5.1.0) от 1 (понедельник) до 7 (воскресенье)

т.е.

```
 1. пн
 2. вт
 3. ср
 4. чт
 5. пт
 6. сб
 7. вс
```

> w  Порядковый номер дня недели от 0 (воскресенье) до 6 (суббота)

```
 0. вс
 1. пн
 2. вт
 3. ср
 4. чт
 5. пт
 6. сб
```

Comment: @ua6xh, вы наверно меня с кем-то перепутали ))) Я превосходно знаю, что и в каком формате должно выводиться. Даты в моих примерах одинаковы? Да. Шаблоны разные? Конечно. А почему результат одинаковый?

Comment: @Deonis - Я же показал вам наглядно, какие дни должны выводиться. Сегодня, 2014-03-21, сегодня пятница и это цифра 5 в обоих стандартах.

Comment: @Deonis - Поставьте дату 2014-03-23  и у вас будут цифры 7 и 0 соответственно.

Comment: @ua6xh, ага. Ну, тады ясно. На примеры я не обратил внимание. По непонятной причине, я ожидал разных результатов. Видать усталость сказывается, пора на отдых ;)

Comment: @Deonis - пятница, пора отдыхать! =) Хороших выходных, @Deonis!![][1]

[1]: https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRT5I9XC0hql0S8bgxh90O65P2OGliMcSwQjUTjU2aFfYj88R3l